# How can i delete rows with zeros from a matrix and rebuild the matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large nxm matrix. Here is some code to set up an example matrix `E` for illustration:

```
E = [(0:9).',[rand(9,3); zeros(1,3)]]
>> E =
0    0.8147    0.9649    0.7922
1    0.9058    0.1576    0.9595
2    0.1270    0.9706    0.6557
3    0.9134    0.9572    0.0357
4    0.6324    0.4854    0.8491
5    0.0975    0.8003    0.9340
6    0.2785    0.1419    0.6787
7    0.5469    0.4218    0.7577
8    0.9575    0.9157    0.7431
9         0         0         0
```

My question is **how can transform matrix `E` into**

```
>> E =
0    0.8147    0.9649    0.7922
1    0.9058    0.1576    0.9595
2    0.1270    0.9706    0.6557
3    0.9134    0.9572    0.0357
4    0.6324    0.4854    0.8491
5    0.0975    0.8003    0.9340
6    0.2785    0.1419    0.6787
7    0.5469    0.4218    0.7577
8    0.9575    0.9157    0.7431
```

**In order to write it to a txt file without the zeros**.

Since the size of this matrix is not fixed, it could have multiple rows like 9 in the above example, or look like

```
>> E =
0    0.8147    0.9649    0.7922
1    0.9058    0.1576    0.9595
2    0.1270    0.9706    0.6557
3    0.9134    0.9572    0.0357
4    0.6324    0.4854    0.8491
5    0.0975    0.8003    0.9340
6    0.2785    0.1419    0.6787
7    0.5469    0.4218    0.7577
8    0.9575    0.9157    0.7431
0         0         0         0
0         0         0         0
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Wolfie yes you are right, it's duplicate

Comment: You can still accept Leander's answer if it does what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Does this cover all cases? If an element in column 2 == 0, delete it.

```
E = E(E(:,2) ~= 0,:);
```

Or if all columns but the first one have to be zero:

```
E = E(all(E(:,2:end) ~= 0,2),:);
```